# display a calendar function on lots of different websites

Tags: calendar

first of all, please excuse my ignorance, this is an exploratory question, rather than a specific programming program that needs solving.

I have a number of clients that have unique websites, none of which I was involved in developing.  I would like them to be able to display a calendar of common events, but which would also contain events unique to them.

Is it possible using something like Server Side Includes to be able to give them a few lines of code which they could insert into their website (on any particular page) which might display a calendar type display, which their users can then interact with?

I guess I am looking for something similar to a Google calendar but I do not want to use a Google calendar.  The key thing would be that they would only need to insert the few lines of code on one of their webpages; they wouldn't have to install any software on their servers.

Any suggestions?

Thanks
Damien

Answer (score 0):

There are are all sorts of web calendars that will allow you to include them on a web page (typically using javascript, not SSI).  Some are targeted at specific platforms (ie, Wordpress) and some are more generic.

Try searching "web calendar widget" for examples.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to put some amount of content on their site. If you can do that, you can include some javascript that will load more javascript from the server side that can do the bulk of the calendaring work for you.

You wouldn't be able to just drop a few files on the server and have them work, you'd need some way to link to them by changing the existing content on at least one of the pages.

I may be misunderstanding your question though.

Comment: When you say I'd have to put some amount of content on their site, what do you mean? Do you mean to install some sort of software?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for specific recommendations on web calendar widgets, [Arshaw's fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) is my favorite to date.

It displays a great calendar that can be easily styled with css or [jquery ui themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) and is very programmable. The website has great documentation and examples as well.

Per using it on different sites, it supports that easily.

Note, I'm not affiliated with that calendar at all, just a satisfied customer.